# Why is deleteIntent(PendingIntent) not called when notification is canceled?

Tags: android

Why is deleteIntent(PendingIntent) not called when notification is canceled?

I am doing this android tutorial on [Notifications](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-notifications/#0) and in the 'extra challenge', am using `deleteIntent`.

However it is not invoked at all. Running in the emulator on API 27.

**When I swipe the notification to cancel, the cancelNotification() method is not called.**

In the docs, I see the watermark ['deprecated' on the page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) but it's not in the text.

Not sure if it's actually deprecated or if I am using `deleteIntent()` wrongly.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-notifications/#6

> In the NotifyMe app, there is one use case in which the state of your
> buttons does not match the state of the app: when a user dismisses a
> notification by swiping it away or clearing the whole notification
> drawer. In this case, your app has no way of knowing that the
> notification was canceled and that the button state must be changed.
>
> Create another pending intent to let the app know that the user has
> dismissed the notification, and toggle the button states accordingly.
>
> Hint: Check out the NotificationCompat.Builder class for a method that
> delivers an Intent if the user dismisses the notification.

```
package com.notifyme;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID = "primary_notification_channel";
    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    private static final String ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION =
            "com.example.android.notifyme.ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION";
    private static final String ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION =
            "com.example.android.notifyme.ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION";
    private NotificationReceiver mReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();

    public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public NotificationReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION:
                    updateNotification();;
                    break;
                case ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION:
                    cancelNotification();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void createNotificationChannel() {
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
                android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Create a NotificationChannel
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Mascot Notification", NotificationManager
                    .IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Notification from Mascot");
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    private Button button_notify;
    private Button button_cancel;
    private Button button_update;

    public void sendNotification() {
        Intent updateIntent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION);
        PendingIntent updatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this, NOTIFICATION_ID, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
        PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this, NOTIFICATION_ID, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = getNotificationBuilder();
        notifyBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_update, "Update Notification", updatePendingIntent);
        notifyBuilder.setDeleteIntent(cancelPendingIntent);
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyBuilder.build());
        setNotificationButtonState(false, true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button_notify = findViewById(R.id.notify);
        button_notify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendNotification();
            }
        });
        createNotificationChannel();
        button_update = findViewById(R.id.update);
        button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Update the notification
                updateNotification();
            }
        });

        button_cancel = findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        button_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Cancel the notification
                cancelNotification();
            }
        });
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,new IntentFilter(ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION));
        setNotificationButtonState(true, false, false);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void updateNotification() {
        Bitmap androidImage = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mascot_1);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = getNotificationBuilder();
        notifyBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(androidImage)
                .setBigContentTitle("Notification Updated!"));
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyBuilder.build());
        setNotificationButtonState(false, false, true);
    }
    public void cancelNotification() {
        mNotifyManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        setNotificationButtonState(true, false, false);
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder(){
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("You've been notified!")
                .setContentText("This is your notification text.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notifyBuilder;
    }
    void setNotificationButtonState(Boolean isNotifyEnabled,
                                    Boolean isUpdateEnabled,
                                    Boolean isCancelEnabled) {
        button_notify.setEnabled(isNotifyEnabled);
        button_update.setEnabled(isUpdateEnabled);
        button_cancel.setEnabled(isCancelEnabled);
    }
}
```

**Update:** From CommonsWare's helpful answer below, I corrected the registration of the receiver to use multiple `Action`s for the same `IntentFilter`. However it still failed even though I tried all the different flags for the `PendingIntent`.
When you press the Update button in the notification and then swipe right, the buttons in the Activity do not reset their states because the `PendingIntent` is not firing.

Here is my updated code.

```
    package com.onedropaflame.notifyme;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
    
    import android.app.NotificationChannel;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID = "primary_notification_channel";
    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    private static final String ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION =
            "com.example.android.notifyme.ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION";
    private static final String ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION =
            "com.example.android.notifyme.ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION";
    private NotificationReceiver mReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();

    public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public NotificationReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION:
                    updateNotification();;
                    break;
                case ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION:
                    cancelNotification();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void createNotificationChannel() {
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
                android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Create a NotificationChannel
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Mascot Notification", NotificationManager
                    .IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Notification from Mascot");
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    private Button button_notify;
    private Button button_cancel;
    private Button button_update;

    public void sendNotification() {
        Intent updateIntent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION);
        PendingIntent updatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this, NOTIFICATION_ID, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
        PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this, NOTIFICATION_ID, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = getNotificationBuilder();
        notifyBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_update, "Update Notification", updatePendingIntent);

        notifyBuilder.setDeleteIntent(cancelPendingIntent);
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyBuilder.build());
        setNotificationButtonState(false, true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button_notify = findViewById(R.id.notify);
        button_notify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendNotification();
            }
        });
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION);
        createNotificationChannel();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,intentFilter);

        button_update = findViewById(R.id.update);
        button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Update the notification
                updateNotification();
            }
        });

        button_cancel = findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        button_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Cancel the notification
                cancelNotification();
            }
        });
        setNotificationButtonState(true, false, false);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void updateNotification() {
        Bitmap androidImage = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mascot_1);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = getNotificationBuilder();
        notifyBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(androidImage)
                .setBigContentTitle("Notification Updated!"));
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyBuilder.build());
        setNotificationButtonState(false, false, true);
    }
    public void cancelNotification() {
        mNotifyManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        setNotificationButtonState(true, false, false);
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder(){
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("You've been notified!")
                .setContentText("This is your notification text.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notifyBuilder;
    }
    void setNotificationButtonState(Boolean isNotifyEnabled,
                                    Boolean isUpdateEnabled,
                                    Boolean isCancelEnabled) {
        button_notify.setEnabled(isNotifyEnabled);
        button_update.setEnabled(isUpdateEnabled);
        button_cancel.setEnabled(isCancelEnabled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonsware posted the correct answer about both actions needing to be registered.
However that was not sufficient.  I corrected the registration of the receiver to use multiple Actions for the same IntentFilter. However it still failed even though I tried all the different flags for the PendingIntent. When you press the Update button in the notification and then swipe right, the buttons in the Activity do not reset their states because the PendingIntent is not firing.

**Solution:** I found that I had to set the `cancelPendingIntent` again during the `updateNotification()`. I do not know the reason why it is lost.

```
public void updateNotification() {
    Bitmap androidImage = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mascot_1);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = getNotificationBuilder();
    notifyBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(androidImage)
            .setBigContentTitle("Notification Updated!"));

// >>>>> SET AGAIN! >>>>>>>>>
    Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
    PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
            (this, NOTIFICATION_ID, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notifyBuilder.setDeleteIntent(cancelPendingIntent);
// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyBuilder.build());
    setNotificationButtonState(false, false, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though you are not registering a receiver for `ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION`, just `ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION`.

Comment: thank you. that was the mistake but it did not fix it entirely. After I click either of the `Update` buttons, it updates the notification, but now swiping the notification removes it but no longer fires the `PendingIntent` to call `cancelNotification()` and reset the button states. Here is how I registered the cancel: ` registerReceiver(mReceiver,new IntentFilter(ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION));`

Comment: @likejudo: That will not work. Either have two separate `BroadcastReceiver` objects or one `IntentFilter` that identifies both actions. Think of receivers as being held in a `HashMap`, keyed by the receiver object. You are doing `put()` twice with the same key.

Comment: This did not work either. `        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,intentFilter);` I even tried changing to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and FLAG_NO_CREATE

Comment: I put all the code in the updated question. I corrected the registration of the receiver to use multiple Actions for the same IntentFilter. However it still failed even though I tried all the different flags for the PendingIntent. When you press the Update button in the notification and then swipe right, the buttons in the Activity do not reset their states because the PendingIntent is not firing.